# Как растянуть блок на всю высоту экрана внутри бесконечного body?

Tags: css

Сабж. Как сделать на js в курсе. Интересует, есть ли решение на css. Сам никак придумать не могу.

Вообще, задача следующая. Есть длинная страница, внутри есть блок сверху. Этот блок должен быть высотой с страницу, т.к. в нём есть форма, которая должна быть по центру.

Comment: Я правда не верстальшик, но что-то подобное краем уха слышал. В процентах вроде никак, только в пикселях.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Я правильно вас понял? [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Nfw8M/)

```css
body {
    width: 5000px;
    height: 5000px;
    background: red;
}
.container {
    background: yellow;
    opacity: .5;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Как банально.

Comment: @ReklatsMasters разве это плохо? решение есть решение

Answer (score 3):

Лучше использовать `vh`:

```
.my_div {
    height:100vh;
}
```

Comment: В IOS 7 есть поддержка vh, но она кривая. Вообще, у vh огромное количество ограничений. Я использую только для домашних проектов.

Answer (score 0):

задать высоту html и body 100% , после чего задать высоту 100% необходимому (дочернему) блоку и он растянется на всю высоту экрана.